# move_arm_warehouse package

Tags: ros, roslib, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've rebuilt ros from sources completely and I don't think it's my installation, but the python script in the move_arm_warehouse package

```
<move_arm_warehouse>./scripts/create_launch_files.py
```

uses the following code

```
directoryName = roslib.packages.is_pkg_dir(robotName + "_arm_navigation")
```

which gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scripts/create_launch_files.py", line 16, in <module>
    if(not roslib.packages.is_pkg_dir(directoryName)):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'is_pkg_dir'
```

anyone else had this problem? is the stack arm_navigation_experimental depreciated to something or not yet updated... or have I don't something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35160/move_arm_warehouse-package/) by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems ROS is planning on phasing out roslib, and leaning toward rospkg, must have missed this one. Anyway the fix is is_pkg_dir has been depreciated to get_pkg_dir - I just edited the script

---

Originally posted by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) with karma: 215 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2012-05-30**:
Did you log a bug for this?

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2012-05-31**:
I'll be releasing a fix into fuerte shortly...

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-05-31**:
I will asap